# How do i host an application

Tags: hosting, shared-hosting

So far i've developed some applications in my career but never really deployed and hosted that. I understand that I can have my own server and make the application accessed public but instead I wanted to go for a 3rd party service provider and I do not understand their type of hosting's which are listed below.

1. Shared hosting
2. managed hosting
3. Virtual Private Servers
4. Dedicated Servers

Can anyone please explain me about those hosting types with an example on which applications can be hosted on such type.
Also can anyone let me know a reliable option to go with when I have an application which runs on tomcat server with MySQL as database and also it should support a website which is developed using word Press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main distinction is between 1/2/3 and 4.

Dedicated servers mean they are hosting only your app. This is more expensive and only needed if your app is requiring very intense and stable ressources.

Any other option means you'll be on a virtual machine : the servers is probably hosting 4 apps, and each one receives a version of the OS and does not see the others. Storage and memory are guaranteed, but bandwidth both on storage and network, may be used by the other apps.
This is OK for 99% of the apps I can think of.

I would not rely on the vocabulary too much, but some options will mean more or less privacy (can the service's admins see you data ?), guarantees (bandwidth) or services (is every possible server/os bundle is available via the service, or do you need to install it from scratch ?).

For instance, Amazon's AWS is nice, and has a lot of out-of-the-box configurations (Apache, TomCat, NodeJS, NGINX...). But most of them rely on old versions (PHP 5.4...). You need to look for non-official configurations if you want to be up-to-date.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks Tristan for detailed explanation. So consider I do not have any sensitive data in my application. Then can I go for 1/2 options??

Comment: Sorry I missed you comment. Yes, go ahead. As I said, this is what 99% of us do.